# Elasticsearch index not created from logstash indexer

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I've setup a simple elastic stack like so:

LS shipper => Kafka => LS Indexer => ES => Kibana

I'm using all the latest versions. (5.2.2-1)

My indices are not being created on Elasticsearch so I've checked at every level.

I can see my logs coming all the way to the LS indexer.

```
[2017-03-14T16:08:01,360][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2017-03-14T15:08:01.355Z, "@version"=>"1", "message"=>"{\"severity\":6,\"timestamp8601\":\"2017-03-14T16:08:01+01:00\",\"pid\":\"65156\",\"program\":\"CROND\",\"message\":\"(root) CMD (/home/unix/cron/iodisk >/dev/null 2>&1)||syslog source origin:not defined or not authorized|syslog source name:not defined or not authorized|syslog source env:not defined or not authorized|syslog source security level:0|syslog time received:2017-03-14T16:08:01.349084+01:00|syslog time reported:2017-03-14T16:08:01+01:00||\\n\",\"priority\":78,\"logsource\":\"VRHNDCPUPAPPPR1\",\"type\":\"system\",\"@timestamp\":\"2017-03-14T15:08:01.000Z\",\"@version\":\"1\",\"host\":\"10.64.1.202\",\"facility\":9,\"severity_label\":\"Informational\",\"source_indexer\":\"tcp.50050\",\"timestamp\":\"2017-03-14T16:08:01+01:00\",\"facility_label\":\"clock\"}"}}
```

Here is my indexer config file:

```
   input {
        kafka {
                bootstrap_servers => "10.64.2.143:9092"
                group_id => "logstash indexer"
                topics => "system"
        }
}
output {
        if [type == "system"] {
                elasticsearch {
                        codec => json
                        hosts => [ "10.64.2.144:9200" ]
                        index => "system"
                }
        }
}
```

Of course, i can't find any index named system in kibana:

[Kibana index pattern configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbztt.png)

[No index created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b3Ga.png)

I'm available for more info if someone is ready to help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your conditional is wrong

```
if [type == "system"] {
```

I suspect that should be:

```
if [type] == "system" {
```

That will probably work better.